# Input text box loosing focus on typing react js

Tags: reactjs

The input text box is loosing focus while typing. Here is the piece of code. Cant understand where is the issue. The following is not the entire code,but it is somewhat like this. Can you please tell me where am I making the mistake

```
var PaymentDetailCard = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            card: {
                        number: "",
                    userName: "",
                    dateWon: "",
                    prepayDue:"",
                    prepayApplied: "",

                    },
            }
    },componentDidMount: function() {
        this.setState( { card: this.props.card } );
   },

   getPrepayAppliedInput:function(){
       var input;
           input = 
           <input
               type="text"
               id="prepayAppliedCard"
               value={this.state.card.prepayApplied}
               onChange={this.change} maxLength ="10" 
       />;
      return( 
           <div><span>$</span>{input}</div>
           )
     },
    change:function(event){ 
           this.setState({prepayApplied: event.target.value});
           PaymentActions.sendRowNum(this.props.rownum);
           {this.props.onPrepayAppliedChange(event)};  
     },
    getUniqueID: function() {
         return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    },
render: function() { 
return (<div>{this.getPrepayAppliedInput()} </div>
)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should move from `React.createClass` to `class PaymentDetailCard extends Component` syntax as Facebook suggests

Secondly, your problem is that you are not binding your `change` function to your class and therefore upon change, `this` points to `input`, not the class itself. When you open your console you will probably see some kind of error because of calling `setState` on this input instead of class.

Also, another comment regarding your code - you shouldn't use `componentDidMount` to initialize the state - move `card: this.props.card` to `getInitialState`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your `onChange` event. Something like this should work:

```
class PaymentDetailCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            card: {
                number: "",
                userName: "",
                dateWon: "",
                prepayDue: "",
                prepayApplied: ""
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({card: this.props.card});
    }


    getPrepayAppliedInput() {
        let input = <input
                        type="text"
                        id="prepayAppliedCard"
                        value={this.state.card.prepayApplied}
                        onChange={this.change.bind(this)} maxLength="10"/>;

        return <div><span>$</span>{input}</div>
    }

    change(event) {
        this.setState({prepayApplied: event.target.value});
        PaymentActions.sendRowNum(this.props.rownum);
        {this.props.onPrepayAppliedChange(event)}
    }


    getUniqueID() {
        return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.getPrepayAppliedInput()} </div>
        )
    }
}

React.render(<PaymentDetailCard />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2819/)